# An error has occurred in the apex chart line type how do I fix it

Tags: reactjs, typescript, apexcharts

```
`series: [
{
name: "High - 2013",
data: [382, 541, 310]
},
{
name: "Low - 2013",
data: [null, null, 1]
}
]
`

ERROR
Cannot read properties of undefined (reading '0')
TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading '0')
at t.value (http://localhost:3000/static/js/bundle.js:155765:29)
at t.value (http://localhost:3000/static/js/bundle.js:156538:101)
at t.value (http://localhost:3000/static/js/bundle.js:156442:154)
at t.value (http://localhost:3000/static/js/bundle.js:156430:98)
at t.value (http://localhost:3000/static/js/bundle.js:156360:144)
at t.value (http://localhost:3000/static/js/bundle.js:156324:80)
at t.value (http://localhost:3000/static/js/bundle.js:156301:19)
```

When I send data as I specified in the graph, it gives an error with a width of 1760px. But when I make the sample 310 value 810 in the data as shown below, 1760px also does not give an error. What is the solution. I'm waiting for your help.

```
`series: [
{
name: "High - 2013",
data: [382, 541, 810]
},
{
name: "Low - 2013",
data: [null, null, 1]
}
]
```

I want this data to work on the chart at 1760px so as not to get an error in my mouse movement